# Show that $M = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A^{-1} \\ \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is a product of elementary matrices, where $A \in GL_n(R)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

If $A\in GL_n(R)$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, I would like to prove
$$
         M=\begin{pmatrix}
          A & 0 \\
          0 & A^{-1} \\
         \end{pmatrix}\in E_{2n}(R),
$$

i.e., $M$ is a product of elementary matrices, where by elementary matrices I mean the matrices obtained by performing elementary row and column operations on the identity matrix $I$ which are defined by $L_j \mapsto \lambda L_i+L_j$ for $L_j$ a column or a row.

I'm trying to solve this question by brute force, making these operations on this matrix and showing this matrix is equivalent to the identity one. I would like to know if there is a simpler and more elegant method to solve this question.

Thanks in advance.